# Python Inherit Module Class

Tags: python, class, oop, inheritance

I have a class with a bunch of generic variables in the **init** method not specific to the class. I want to make another class that holds these variables and then have the first class inheritance those variables.

So the second class is not a parent class, but more like a module class.

How I write this in python?

Thanks.

```
Class A():
   def __init__(self):
       self.generic_variable1 = 'blah'
       self.generic_variable2 = 'blah'
       self.generic_variable3 = 'blah'
       self.generic_variable4 = 'blah'
       self.generic_variable5 = 'blah'
       self.generic_variable6 = 'blah'
   
   def generic_method1(self):
       return 'blah'
   
   def class_specific_method1(self):
       pass
```

---

After creating two classes:

```
Class A():
   def __init__(self):
       pass
   
   def class_specific_method1(self):
       pass

Class B():
   def __init__(self):
       self.generic_variable1 = 'blah'
       self.generic_variable2 = 'blah'
       self.generic_variable3 = 'blah'
       self.generic_variable4 = 'blah'
       self.generic_variable5 = 'blah'
       self.generic_variable6 = 'blah'
   
   def generic_method1(self):
       return 'blah'
```

Comment: It kind of sounds like you are describing a mixin, but without *any* code it's hard to know for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A module level dictionary that the class can access.

```
d = {'k':'v','q':'r','m':'n',...}

class F:
    variables = d
    def __init__(self,...)
```

Or maybe a collections.namedtuple instead of a dictionary to give you *dot* access - `instance.variables.attr` instead of instance.variables[attr]` .

If you want individual attributes:

```
d = {'k':'v','q':'r','m':'n'}

class F:
    def __init__(self):
        for attr,val in d.items():
            setattr(self,attr,val)
```

Or set the attributes outside of the class

```
d = {'k':'v','q':'r','m':'n'}

class F:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

for k,v in d.items():
    setattr(F,k,v)
```

Comment: That doesnt sound clean though. Then I have to unpack those variables.

Comment: Does what Geroge said works on just inheriting the class? Dont we only inherit if its parent child though right?

Comment: @BoPeng - see edit. Using inheritance will accomplish what you want. Whether there has to be a parent/child relationship to use inheritance sounds like a philosophical question there is certainly no technical requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Just simply

```
class A:
    ... ...
    
class B(A):
    ... ...
```

In class B, if you do not rewrite `__init__`, it will automatically use class A's.

If you need do extra thing in class B's `__init__`:

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super().__init__(*args, **kw)
        ... ...
```

Comment: Hi George, thanks for that. I thought we only inherit if its a parent child relationship. This is more like inheriting a bunch of generic variables that are not specific to the class that I want to create a new class to inherit to make the first class look cleaner. Thanks

Comment: @BoPeng 老哥，你也是国人吧，说实话我没搞懂你啥意思，要不你用中文说下 Seems that you know Chinese, would you explain in Chinese again? I don't really understand what you meant.